# Import 2 attachments in same Drive's folder (created if he doesn't exists)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am currently developing an application to make requests. These requests can be accompanied by two attachments. These are not mandatory, there can be none, one or two.)
If there are any, they will be saved in a specific folder on the Drive. This folder is a child folder created automatically and named after the id of the request.
So I created a script to import the attachments when a button is clicked since I need to get the id and url of the attachment to add it to the Sheets file.
However, I have a problem when there are two attachments. Indeed, this generates two folders with the same name (the id of the request) whereas I would like them to be grouped in the same folder.

Here is the html code of the attachments :

```
  <div class="form-row divHtml" id="divPhotos">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="photoPres" class="txtPhoto"><b>Photo de près :</b></label><br>
      <input type="file" id="photoPres">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="photoLoin" class="txtPhoto"><b>Photo de loin :</b></label><br>
      <input type="file" id="photoLoin">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row divHtml">
    <div class="form-group col-8">
      <input type="button" id = "btnFichiers" value="IMPORTER LES PHOTOS" onclick="getFiles()">
      <p id="idPhotoPres" class="invisible"></p>
      <p id="idPhotoLoin" class="invisible"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the corresponding javascript :

```
   function getFiles(){
     const f = document.getElementById('photoPres');
     if (f.files.length > 0){   
       [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
         const fr = new FileReader();
         fr.onload = (e) => {
           const data = e.target.result.split(",");
           const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(id => {
             document.getElementById("idPhotoPres").innerHTML = id
           }).saveFile(obj);
         }
         fr.readAsDataURL(file);
       });
     }
     const f2 = document.getElementById('photoLoin');
     if (f2.files.length > 0){    
       [...f2.files].forEach((file2, i) => {
         const fr2 = new FileReader();
         fr2.onload = (e) => {
           const data = e.target.result.split(",");
           const obj = {fileName: f2.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
        document.getElementById("idPhotoLoin").innerHTML = id;
           }).saveFile(obj);
         }
         fr2.readAsDataURL(file2);
       });
     }
   }
```

And here is the apps script code for the back-end part:

```
function saveFile(obj){
   var pieceJointe = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
   const dossierDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById('1KRwd79dc8k8EArwHU_1RnkDHd-Sdv0DJ');

   const idDemande = generateId().toString();
   var dossierPieceJointe;
   var idDosssier = folderExists(idDemande);
   if (idDosssier !== false) { 
     dossierPieceJointe = DriveApp.getFolderById(idDosssier);
     const pieceJointeAjoutee = dossierPieceJointe.createFile(pieceJointe);
     const informationsPJ = {
       'url' : pieceJointeAjoutee.getUrl(),
       'id' : pieceJointeAjoutee.getId()
     };
     return informationsPJ;
   } else {
     dossierPieceJointe = dossierDrive.createFolder(idDemande);
     const pieceJointeAjoutee = dossierPieceJointe.createFile(pieceJointe);
     const informationsPJ = {
       'url' : pieceJointeAjoutee.getUrl(),
     };
     return informationsPJ;
   }
 }


 function generateId(){
   const classeur =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const webAppSheet = classeur.getSheetByName("Demandes");
   var lastRow = webAppSheet.getLastRow();
   var splitId = []; var id; var lastDemande = "";

   if(lastRow == 1){
     return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_1";
   }else{
     lastDemande = webAppSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
     splitId = lastDemande.split('_');
     if (splitId[0] == new Date().getFullYear()){
       id = lastId + 1;
       feuilleBDD.getRange("I2").setValue(id);
       return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_" + id;
     }
     else {
       feuilleBDD.getRange("I2").setValue(1)
       return (new Date().getFullYear()) + "_1";
     }
   }
 }

 function folderExists(nomDossierPJ) {
   const dossierDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById('1KRwd79dc8k8EArwHU_1RnkDHd-Sdv0DJ');
   var folders = dossierDrive.getFolders();
   var theReturn = false,folderName = "",folder;  
   while (folders.hasNext()) {
     folder = folders.next();
     folderName = folder.getName();

     if (folderName === nomDossierPJ) {
       theReturn = folder.getId();
       break;
     };
   };
   return theReturn;
 }
```

Could you please help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are the functions of `generateId()` and `folderExists(idDemande)`?

Comment: Sorry Tanaike, i missed them. I edit my post, they re in Apps Script's part. The first generate an id depending of other id created. The second return true if the child folder exist and false if not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. By guessing your situation, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current issue and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your showing script, I'm worried that in your script, the reason for your issue might be due to that `FileReader` and `google.script.run` are run with the asynchronous process. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

In this modification, your Javascript is modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function getResponse(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = { fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1] };
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(reject).withSuccessHandler(resolve).saveFile(obj);
    }
    if (file) {
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      reject("No file");
    }
  });
}

async function getFiles() {
  const f1 = document.getElementById('photoPres');
  const f2 = document.getElementById('photoLoin');
  const files = [{ f: f1.files[0], disp: "idPhotoPres" }, { f: f2.files[0], disp: "idPhotoLoin" }];
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (!files[i].f) continue;
    const { url } = await getResponse(files[i].f).catch(err => console.log(err));
    document.getElementById(files[i].disp).innerHTML = url;
  }
}
```

- By this modification, the files are uploaded with the synchronous process. By this, I thought that your issue might be able to be removed.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about your actual situation. If you are using Web Apps, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script in the Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I'm sorry Tanaike but I've an error when i want to add my files in Drive  "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'url' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
    at getFiles (<anonymous>:281:13)".

Comment: In line 281, I've "const { url } = await getResponse(files[i].f).catch(err => console.log(err));"

Comment: @devMethodes About your new question of `I've an error when i want to add my files in Drive. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'url' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined. at getFiles (<anonymous>:281:13)`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot replicate it. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @devMethodes I think that the reason that I can test my script without errors is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. So, when you post it as a new question, please include the detailed flow for correctly replicating your new issue.

Comment: @devMethodes I think that my English skill is very poor. So, I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my comments. If you cannot understand my English. Please tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251211/discussion-between-devmethodes-and-tanaike).